# Write to jsp file from Java file

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a Java web service designed using Spring and a jsp file corresponding to it.

To further clarify, I have a jsp file called infosys.jsp WEB-INF/views which can be accessed like https:// localhost:8080/admin/infosys?id=34. I can pass in parameters too as shown.

In my web controller I have a method called

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/infosys", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public @ResponseBody void getId(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false) String id) {
    .......
}
```

I have debugged and this method works, I can access the id passed it. I am trying to display the id in my jsp file. For example if I say https:// localhost:8080/admin/infosys I want to be able to display 34. How can I write to my jsp file? I have a MySQL db intergrate if i need to store and access. If I need that how can I write to DB and access??

EDIT: infosys.jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored ="false" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Info Sys</title>
</head>
<body>
<spring:url value="/" var="homeUrl"/>
<a href="${homeUrl}">Home</a>
<BR><BR>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The phrases `display the id in my jsp file` and `write to my jsp file` indicate some fundamental misunderstanding about what a jsp file is. It is not something you "write to". It is a template for rendering HTML output.

Comment: Sorry I am new to web services. How do I render an HTML output?

Comment: I'm not convinced that Stackoverflow is the place for tutorials. http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html

Answer (score 6):

Your Controller's Handler Method should return a String (no @ResponseBody) with the name of the view. You should also set your ID in a model.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/infosys", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String getId(@RequestParam(value="id", required=false) String id, org.springframework.ui.Model model) {

  model.addAttribute("id", id);
  return "admin/infosys";
}
```

You should use Spring's InternalResourceViewResolver to turn that returned value into the relative path to the view. You would add that as a bean in your Web Application Context Configuration file, usually at `/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

`admin/infosys` -> InternalResourceViewResolver -> `/WEB-INF/views/admin/infosys.jsp`;

Here's how it works:

1. Http request to say, Tomcat
2. Request is handled by Spring's DispatcherServlet
3. DispatcherServlet finds correct HandlerMethod based on @RequestMapping
4. DispatcherServlet creates a Model instance and passes to HandlerMethod by reference
5. HandlerMethod returns view name to DispatcherServlet
6. Spring adds model to Request scope
7. DispatcherServlet gets view path from InternalResourceViewResolver
8. Finds correct JSP
9. Forwards request to JSP

In your JSP file, simple put `${id}` anywhere in the page and this will be show the value of the "id" model attribute.

Comment: Thank you! This works. When I make the call with the parameters, it now redirects me to the infosys.jsp page. However, it does not display the parameters. I have posted the infosys.jsp file. I am not sure where to add the modelAttribute aspect to show the output.

Comment: thanks! that worked. Also, I was wondering if I wanted to save this id into a mySQL db, how can I do that? I am using Spring. Right now its only showing the id from the most recent https get call. My ultimate goal is to save the ids from multiple HTTPS GET calls and show all the ids

Comment: That's a whole new, large topic :) I would suggest using Spring Data JPA. Start here: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/